# Responsive centering of divs

Tags: css, responsive

How do I go from here

[image]

To here

[image]

I'm trying to center the inner div's to their parent except for the last row where I'd like to align it left to the row above it.

Here is the jsfiddle for the top image https://jsfiddle.net/L15p2nev

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: green;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    item
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you really want to do? you spread the items when the screen has enough width and then you need to stack each item on top of another where the stack of items are horizontally centered in the parent. Is that what you want?

Comment: If you want to use flexbox, you have to apply height to container in order to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `grid` display layout, this can be archived.

You can set `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 300px)` to align items as the image.

```css
.container {
  background-color: green;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 300px);
  justify-content: center;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    item
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item
  </div>
</div>
```